# Why would a model combining two pre-trained models not even achieve the performance of the best sub-model?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, hyperparameter, ensemble-learning, stacking

I have two different CNNs trained on the same dataset. One performs a bit better than the other but I believe each can provide different and useful information.

I use `pytorch`. Each model consists in convolution and pooling layers, followed by a couple of linear layers and a final linear layer that acts as classifier (output size of 2).
What I've done is train each model independently. Then, the combined model takes the output of the last linear layer before the classifier of each model, concatenates them, and passes them through a feed-forward network.

I assumed that even if it could not improve the performance, the combined model would at least perform as well as the best sub-model. However, I can't even seem to achieve that, the performance always stays midway between the performances of both models.

To build each model I am using the `optuna` framework to optimize the hyper-parameters. Tuning the combined model should be much simpler than tuning the others since the only hyper-parameters I am optimizing about the structure of the net are the amount of hidden layers and their sizes (apart from other parameters such as lr, scheduler or optimizer).
Almost from the first trial, the study achieves the max performance and stays there, unable to improve it.

I have also tried normalizing each of the models `outputa` (separately) before concatenating, as well as applying a `relu` or `tanh` activation, without any luck.

Note: I am supposedly disabling training for the pre-trained models when training the combined one by doing this:

```
for param in model.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False
```

just in case this could be failing and the models could be being trained somehow

**More notes:**
I am using AUROC to assess the validation results due to class imbalance and got  0.823 and 0.845 for each sub-model and just tonight managed to go from 0.83 to 0.840 for the combined one, still a bit under 0.845. I still need to look more into how they differ but a quick look revealed their predictions do differ for some of the samples  (meaning each of them is able to detect the positive class in some cases the other cannot). Is the difference between 0.845 and 0.840 too small to think there'a a problem at all? Maybe they simply cannot improve the result? I really think they should as I believe each CNN can capture different aspects of the data but I don't know what else to try.

**More detail, as requested:**
AUROC

Model 1 (best val AUROC is 0.8215):

```
epoch#0 "train: 0.6366974115371704. val: 0.7702255249023438"
epoch#1 "train: 0.7658864259719849. val: 0.8044375777244568"
epoch#2 "train: 0.7930459976196289. val: 0.8081876039505005"
epoch#3 "train: 0.808762788772583. val: 0.8145741820335388"
epoch#4 "train: 0.8074648380279541. val: 0.819037914276123"
epoch#5 "train: 0.8217006921768188. val: 0.8215399980545044"
epoch#6 "train: 0.8180385828018188. val: 0.8036410212516785"
epoch#7 "train: 0.8230613470077515. val: 0.8032418489456177"
epoch#8 "train: 0.8317129611968994. val: 0.794983983039856"
epoch#9 "train: 0.831802248954773. val: 0.7899027466773987"
```

Model 2 (best val AUROC is 0.8459):

```
epoch#0 "train: 0.7058017253875732. val: 0.809760332107544"
epoch#1 "train: 0.763457179069519. val: 0.8283499479293823"
epoch#2 "train: 0.7822374701499939. val: 0.8328834772109985"
epoch#3 "train: 0.792770266532898. val: 0.8357023000717163"
epoch#4 "train: 0.8013472557067871. val: 0.8357467651367188"
epoch#5 "train: 0.7995779514312744. val: 0.8434610366821289"
epoch#6 "train: 0.8074525594711304. val: 0.8365026712417603"
epoch#7 "train: 0.8083140254020691. val: 0.8424113988876343"
epoch#8 "train: 0.8113613128662109. val: 0.840691089630127"
epoch#9 "train: 0.8122062683105469. val: 0.8387175798416138"
epoch#10 "train: 0.8135561347007751. val: 0.83888840675354"
epoch#11 "train: 0.8170522451400757. val: 0.8417861461639404"
epoch#12 "train: 0.8170279264450073. val: 0.8459413051605225"
epoch#13 "train: 0.8188912272453308. val: 0.8401663303375244"
epoch#14 "train: 0.815981388092041. val: 0.8426406383514404"
epoch#15 "train: 0.8164429664611816. val: 0.8418955206871033"
epoch#16 "train: 0.81856369972229. val: 0.844316840171814"
epoch#17 "train: 0.8204455971717834. val: 0.8412182331085205"
epoch#18 "train: 0.8213235139846802. val: 0.8446505069732666"
epoch#19 "train: 0.8185620307922363. val: 0.8446468710899353"
epoch#20 "train: 0.8193531036376953. val: 0.8453472852706909"
epoch#21 "train: 0.824106752872467. val: 0.8401384353637695"
epoch#22 "train: 0.8230797052383423. val: 0.8440967798233032"
epoch#23 "train: 0.8226444721221924. val: 0.844730794429779"
epoch#24 "train: 0.8208979368209839. val: 0.8456006050109863"
epoch#25 "train: 0.8220465183258057. val: 0.8424403667449951"
epoch#26 "train: 0.8219859600067139. val: 0.8446440696716309"
epoch#27 "train: 0.8249871730804443. val: 0.8453245162963867"
epoch#28 "train: 0.8226014375686646. val: 0.8424029350280762"
epoch#29 "train: 0.8257030248641968. val: 0.844139575958252"
```

Combined model:

```
epoch#0 "train: 0.6831338405609131. val: 0.8345752954483032"
epoch#1 "train: 0.6995154619216919. val: 0.8403782248497009"
epoch#2 "train: 0.7099341154098511. val: 0.8315378427505493"
epoch#3 "train: 0.7238966822624207. val: 0.8292025923728943"
```

The combined model has few epochs because optuna pruned it.
The combined model overfits less on the training dataset due to dropout I guess. With the CNNs seems more difficult to prevent as Model 1 does seem to overfit quickly even with quite a lot of dropout.

Training data size is around 70k and validation data size is around 24k. The data is highly imbalanced (only around 5% are positives) and I use WeightedRandomSampler for the training set so not all training data is used in all epochs.

Comment: What are the training and validation scores for each model (pretrained model 1, pretrained model 2, combined model)? The simplest explanation is that one of the pretrained models is significantly worse than the other, because of the inherent instability in training NNs.

Comment: And do you have a reference for the ensembling procedure you're running?
Most NN ensembles simply average predictions from many NNs trained w/ different random inits or hyperparameters, on the same dataset. Even these ensembles don't always outperform the highest-scoring model in terms of accuracy/discrimination. They do result in [significantly better calibration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474).

Comment: I added some notes based on what you asked. I am not looking to ensemble the final predictions of the model, I am trying to learn from the combined features extracted by the CNNs. I think it is different because it should give more insight to the network than just receiving two 0-1 predictions and learning which  model to listen to. It is basically as if the last part of a CNN received data from separate chains of convolutions and therefore had more extracted features to work with. Am I making sense? @chicxulub

Comment: Thank you for the extra details. Can you add the training AUROCs too? I'm curious to see how much the ensembling procedure reduces bias (higher training AUROC), which is what you're after. Re "Is the difference between 0.845 and 0.840 too small to think there'a a problem at all?", can you also add the size of the validation set?

Comment: It's hard to theoretically reason about your particular ensembling procedure. It seems well-motivated. Perhaps further experimentation will help. For example, what happens if you enable training for the pretrained models when training the combined one?

Comment: Also when I said "average predictions" (in my second comment) I meant "average predicted probabilities", not the binarized 0-1 predictions. You don't need to train anything / learn which model to listen to; just run the 2 models and average the softmaxed-scores. It's a simple baseline to beat, especially if your model's downstream application relies on good probability scores AKA calibration.

Comment: I added  more details, I hope it helps. And thanks for the last clarification! I will try that as well then, although I'd really want to make the combined one work or at least understand why the feed-forward network is not able to learn at least what the separate network learnt

Comment: I will also try to enable training for the models and see what happens

Comment: Just chiming in here -- optimizing neural networks is tricky, the performance will highly depend on the training dynamics. Something to consider is that concatenating two outputs will result in a bigger Weight matrix in the subsequent feedforward layer. This could make it sensitive to larger learning rates -- you may want to try adding a `LayerNormalization` layer after the concat to help keep training more stable.

Comment: @Variational thanks for the suggestion. I was using `F.normalize`. How does `LayerNormalization`  differ from that? (although I guess you meant `torch.nn.LayerNorm`) I will try, I guess I'd need to use it with `normalized_shape` equal to each model's output size.